# SecItemCopyMatching keeps returning errSecItemNotFound

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I'm trying to use Keychain Services to save a value, which would persist even if a user reinstalls the app. So I check if an item exists using `SecItemCopyMatching`, which returns `errSecItemNotFound` the first time and add a new item using `SecItemAdd`, which returns `errSecSuccess`, but the value of `_attrs` is `nil`. Also, when the code is called second time, the `SecItemCopyMatching` still returns `errSecItemNotFound`, as if `SecItemAdd` wasn't called. So what that could be related to?

```
    CFMutableDictionaryRef _attrs = nil;
    NSString* key = @"<unique key>";
    NSMutableDictionary* query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    query[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel] = key;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit] = (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes] = (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue;

    OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef*)&_attrs);

    if (err == errSecSuccess) {
        return YES;
    }
    NSString* str = @"<some data>";
    if (err == errSecItemNotFound) {
        query[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = NSData_from_string(string_from_NSString(str));
        query[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible] = (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways;
        err = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef*)&_attrs);
        assert(err == errSecSuccess);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-using `query` for your call to `SecItemAdd`, and the `kSecMatchLimit` value being present in the dictionary for this function is breaking it.  You should remove this key before calling `SecItemAdd`.

It's also worth noting that `[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` might be a better choice than whatever  `NSData_from_string(string_from_NSString(str))` is, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: It seems that it works, but I don't quite understand why. Is `kSecMatch` key not applicable to `SecItemAdd`, or if I would use `kSecMatchAll` that would pass? I can't remember coming across this while reading the docs...

Comment: The documentation for `SecItemCopyMatching` indicates that you can add items from the "Search Constants" section of the documentation (such as `kSecMatchLimit`) to the query.  The `SecItemAdd` documentation does not indicate this, and it appears that such constants being present in the query will break the call (or at least make it not behave as you might expect).